# Identify in which screen instance a process is running

Tags: process, gnu-screen

A process listening on port 8113 (Solr) is not responding. I've found its PID via `netstat` but the server has about two dozen Solr process running in various `screen` sessions.

```
3607.foobar-client2  (12/27/14 20:54:02)     (Detached)
3797.solr.bo.app    (12/25/14 11:51:30)     (Detached)
2962.solr       (12/25/14 11:47:23)     (Detached)
1410.solrTester         (12/25/14 11:39:41)     (Detached)
1348.solrReports (12/25/14 11:38:41)     (Detached)
....
```

The only way that I've found to identify them involves stopping the processes. I tried identifying them by which files are open by `lsof` but that was not helpful at all in this circumstance. **Is there any way to determine, based on PID, in which `screen` session a process is running?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Found it!**

To find the `screen` instance in which PID 351 is running, search the PID 351 environment for the string "STY=":

```
$ grep -z '^STY=' /proc/351/environ
STY=1410.neverFindMe
```

Or using `ps` (if screen session names don't contain space characters):

```
$ ps wwep 351 | grep -o 'STY=\S*'
STY=1410.neverFindMe
```

Comment: Thank you Stéphane! You might post that edit as another answer, as it adds very useful information, I would accept it.